# Android SyncService destroyed exactly after 120 seconds

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, syncservices

can someone explain me why SyncService is destroyed exactly after 120 seconds after it is created?

Also strange thing is that SyncAdapter method onPerformSync is still running after SyncService is destroyed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the function is running after the Service is detroyed is normal.  You can't just stop a thread from outside (without knowing a lot about how the thread works).  You could break the app, corrupt data, or cause a deadlock.  So Android doesn't even try.  Destroying the Service just changes some bookkeeping and prevents some things that require a Context from working, it doesn't stop any threads that are running.

Stopping after 120 seconds-  sounds like the timer for background services.  Did you call startForeground()?

Comment: No, I didn't call startForegorund(), SyncService is called after successful adding account into account manager with setSyncAutomatically set to true, because I can see spining icon next to Contacts in accounts. But that spining icon stops after SyncService is destroyed but really SyncAdapter is still working. So it is wrong information that syncing is over.

Comment: If you have a service you want to run in the background, when your UI isn't resident, you must call startForeground on modern versions of Android.  If not it will be killed.  But it being killed wouldn't cause bad data, if you're seeing bad data there's something else wrong in your service.

Comment: But how to call startForeground on sync service? I am not calling that sync service from my code. I just tap sync icon in account manager under my account which is then calling my service.

Comment: Your service, whatever it is, should be calling it